# Testing android module

Tags: android, android-fragments, junit

I had a module in Android application. Main idea of this module is creating the Fragment. I created some unit test for it, but for testing fragment need to create Activity. Is it possible test this module without activity and application?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Test Activity in the debug build variant. That will not get packaged into the release. Then write the test so that it uses the Test Activity to bind to the Fragment. Though the documentation does not state this clearly, you can have Instrumentation Tests running only for a module also.

Therefore your code structure would look like this -

```
src
-main
-debug
 - TestActivity.java
```